# Inputs clearing on page load

Tags: jquery, forms, magento

I'm having a problem where certain inputs are being cleared after the page fully loads. Right now, on document ready, certain inputs are being populated with jQuery. This part is working fine, however when the page fully loads, certain inputs are cleared. Text inputs, checkboxes and select options retain their value, however radio buttons and textareas are cleared out. The only way that I noticed this is that one page contains a very large image that takes some time to download. While that image is loading, all inputs show the proper value, however immediately after the image finishes loading, everything clears. 
In addition, in Chrome, the textarea disappears. It still shows up in the inspector as taking up space, and if you just change a css property through the inspector, like padding, it reappears.
Would there be any reason that a form would clear out certain inputs on page load? The site is a Magento site and is using jquery 1.7.2. Thanks for any help you may be able to provide!

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the bug image in chunks and after Onload complete.